# Sending always a null string parameter in RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a method to read content of a file like below:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ActionName(nameof(ReadFile))]

    public ActionResult ReadFile(FileContentViewModel obj)
    {

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(obj.FilePath, FileMode.Open);
        string fileContent ;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            fileContent = reader.ReadLine();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("FileReader", "File", fileContent);


    }
```

and at the end of the method I want to pass fileContent to below method

```
  public ActionResult FileReader(string fileContent)
    {


        return View(new FileContentViewModel() { FileContent=fileContent});
    }
```

Although fileStream has value in first method, but it is always sent with value null once I redirect to the second method.

Comment: `RedirectToAction("FileReader", "File", new {fileContent});`

Comment: You may need to send your data via `TempData` or set a `cookie` (better approach) from `ReadFile` controller to `FileReader` controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect with parameter, you can use:

```
return RedirectToAction("FileReader", "File", new { fileContent= fileContent});
```

[image]